# Count rows in table behind CA70

Tags: sap-erp

I have an SAP table that I need to extract data from.

Does anyone know how I can count the number of lines that are in this SAP table
if anyone is familiar with SAP, it is transaction `CA70` (where used)

[image: screen print]

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a programmatic way to get record count, you can use the SAP standard RFC function `EM_GET_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES`. Please notice this function does not take WHERE clause.